# quantifying fluctuation of data over a time period

Tags: pandas, statistics, pandas-groupby

I have a data frame as shown below

```html
Time Detrended
101.048 -0.004
107.979 -0.021
111.05 -0.006
116.052 -0.005
121.055 -0.012
126.058 -0.013
131.06 -0.011
136.053 -0.011
141.068 -0.006
146.063 -0.007
151.063 -0.006
156.065 -0.018
161.077 -0.013
166.065 -0.004
171.698 -0.004
176.076 -0.02
181.072 -0.003
186.078 -0.02
191.074 -0.011
196.08 -0.003
201.083 -0.009
206.084 -0.006
211.086 -0.011
216.079 -0.012
221.092 -0.014
226.087 -0.016
231.088 -0.007
236.092 -0.013
241.096 -0.007
246.098 -0.012
251.103 -0.009
256.095 -0.005
261.104 -0.014
266.105 -0.008
271.109 -0.007
276.111 -0.012
281.112 -0.015
286.115 -0.01
291.117 -0.011
296.12 -0.015
301.115 0.003
306.119 -0.004
311.123 -0.006
316.123 -0.004
321.127 -0.016
326.129 -0.013
331.131 -0.003
336.132 -0.021
341.136 -0.017
346.138 -0.004
351.142 -0.015
356.142 -0.006
361.138 -0.017
366.14 -0.008
371.971 -0.006
376.143 -0.004
381.147 -0.062
386.148 -0.05
391.15 -0.055
396.153 -0.047
401.166 -0.05
406.157 -0.065
411.16 -0.051
416.162 -0.013
421.173 0.004
426.166 -0.002
431.168 -0.007
436.164 -0.007
441.176 -0.026
446.168 -0.004
451.171 -0.014
456.171 -0.011
461.175 -0.016
466.177 -0.013
471.18 -0.021
476.181 -0.019
481.187 -0.007
486.185 -0.025
491.185 -0.019
496.188 -0.029
501.192 -0.026
506.193 -0.036
511.199 -0.009
516.196 -0.022
521.205 -0.033
526.203 -0.016
531.201 -0.029
536.202 -0.027
541.204 -0.022
546.205 -0.031
551.217 -0.028
556.211 -0.031
561.216 -0.016
566.221 -0.024
571.223 -0.037
576.218 -0.031
581.219 -0.019
586.226 -0.022
591.232 -0.014
596.23 -0.025
601.236 -0.028
606.85 -0.021
611.232 -0.015
616.238 -0.022
621.243 -0.017
626.236 -0.016
631.239 -0.016
636.246 -0.024
641.248 -0.014
646.251 -0.016
651.252 -0.02
656.255 -0.032
661.257 -0.01
666.259 -0.045
671.254 -0.032
676.257 -0.049
681.264 -0.037
686.266 -0.003
691.261 0.023
696.264 -0.001
701.269 -0.007
706.265 -0.024
711.276 -0.017
716.279 -0.021
721.273 -0.023
726.28 -0.029
731.281 -0.022
736.284 -0.016
741.29 -0.024
746.282 -0.013
751.282 -0.012
756.287 -0.024
761.29 -0.02
766.291 -0.027
771.302 -0.019
776.294 -0.025
781.297 -0.015
786.302 -0.012
791.304 -0.021
796.3 -0.013
801.303 -0.018
806.304 -0.005
811.315 -0.036
816.309 -0.024
821.319 -0.023
826.313 -0.009
831.315 -0.039
836.318 -0.001
841.322 -0.005
846.328 -0.005
851.323 -0.021
856.325 0.011
861.327 -0.009
866.333 0.002
871.334 -0.014
876.336 -0.014
881.337 -0.009
886.341 -0.002
891.344 -0.01
896.348 -0.024
901.35 -0.015
906.353 -0.006
911.354 -0.011
916.357 -0.009
921.352 -0.003
926.356 0.01
931.358 0.011
936.362 0.006
941.364 -0.002
946.366 -0.007
951.367 -0.001
956.371 -0.004
961.372 -0.027
966.368 0.002
971.379 -0.005
981.377 -0.019
986.376 0.009
991.387 -0.011
996.39 0.007
1001.391 -0.003
1006.384 -0.001
1011.388 -0.003
1021.401 -0.006
1026.394 -0.013
1036.398 -0.008
1041.403 0.003
1046.409 -0.005
1051.41 -0.013
1056.406 -0.014
1061.408 0.003
1066.41 -0.017
1071.412 0.008
1076.415 0.002
1081.416 0.006
1086.419 0.004
1091.421 0.002
1096.424 0.005
1101.425 -0.014
1106.428 0.015
1111.43 -0.003
1116.426 -0.003
1121.43 -0.014
1126.436 -0.019
1131.438 -0.003
1136.44 -0.004
1141.442 0.009
1151.45 0.005
1156.441 -0.007
1166.445 -0.006
1171.455 0.013
1181.451 -0.004
1186.457 0.014
1196.461 -0.013
1201.462 -0.018
1206.464 -0.007
1211.466 0.001
1216.463 -0.006
1221.471 -0.001
1226.473 -0.012
1231.474 0.003
1236.478 -0.003
1246.472 -0.011
1251.477 0.003
1256.483 0.006
1261.485 -0.009
1266.48 0.008
1271.485 -0.006
1276.486 -0.003
1281.489 -0.015
1286.492 -0.004
1291.493 0.003
1296.489 -0.01
1301.493 -0.012
1306.497 -0.007
1311.5 -0.006
1316.493 0.001
1321.496 -0.008
1326.509 -0.013
1331.5 0.007
1336.503 -0.003
1341.505 -0.011
1346.517 -0.005
1351.519 -0.003
1356.512 -0.021
1366.513 -0.015
1371.52 -0.015
1376.518 0.005
1381.519 -0.011
1386.522 -0.008
1391.523 -0.012
1396.524 -0.001
1401.526 -0.008
1406.528 -0.012
1411.531 -0.016
1416.532 -0.014
1421.535 -0.014
1426.538 -0.014
1431.54 -0.005
1436.541 -0.023
1441.543 -0.016
1446.546 -0.016
1451.547 -0.014
1456.544 -0.004
1461.55 -0.022
1466.553 -0.003
1471.555 -0.001
1476.55 -0.025
1481.556 -0.01
1486.554 -0.03
1491.559 -0.015
1496.562 -0.018
1501.564 -0.036
1506.566 -0.026
1511.568 -0.026
1516.561 0.004
1521.565 -0.008
1526.568 0.01
1531.571 -0.002
1541.567 -0.015
1546.577 -0.005
1551.579 -0.031
1556.574 -0.016
1561.576 -0.025
1566.579 -0.016
1571.58 0.009
1576.589 0.004
1581.584 -0.013
1586.587 -0.047
1591.588 -0.039
1596.594 -0.046
1601.586 -0.033
1606.599 0.006
1616.619 0.012
1622.765 0.02
1626.6 0.001
1631.6 0.007
1636.603 0.009
1641.609 -0.014
1651.606 0.01
1656.611 0.004
1661.614 -0.004
1666.611 -0.022
1671.612 -0.017
1676.617 -0.027
1681.619 0.005
1686.618 -0.002
1691.624 0.004
1696.621 -0.009
1701.627 -0.009
1706.628 -0.012
1711.633 -0.006
1716.634 -0.011
1721.633 -0.028
1726.639 -0.007
1731.637 -0.003
1736.639 -0.002
1741.645 -0.009
1746.647 -0.01
1751.649 -0.011
1756.651 -0.022
1761.647 -0.04
1766.649 -0.019
1771.651 -0.012
1776.654 0.007
1781.656 0.002
1786.658 -0.025
1791.653 -0.011
1796.655 0.003
```

When I do a line plot on the data, it is as below (without the pink line).
The pink line shows that the data mostly went down but recovered to come up. it is important for me to quantify this swing (amount of down & up).
If there is a way to find the area under the curve or anything that would quantify this, that would be very helpful.
There may be other methods that can help me quantify this swing/fluctuation. Can anyone guide me to quantifying this(Area **above** and **below** the curve are both needed)?

In my complete dataframe, i have several groups that are similar to the data posted below. so, if the code you suggest would work on groupby object, that would be awesome.Thanks.

[image]

Comment: It looks like you want a smooth curve **after** removal of outliers. There are some technique for smoothing, such as rolling mean or exponential weighted mean. However, it's neither easy nor obvious as how to remove outliers.

Comment: i am not worried about the outliers, i am more interested in the quantifying the movement of the center axis of the curve. i have dome rolling mean but that does not give me one value to quantify the whole dataset. i need one value(or multiple one values) which quantifies the swing of the dataset mean

Answer (score 0):

Try to add zero axis by just making a column having zero in it.

create moving averages by apply different windows size.You can study [rolling window](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.rolling.html) from the link

I hope it would solve your problem

```
df['zero'] = 0
df['MA'] = df['Detrended'].rolling(window=100).mean()

fig = plt.figure()
ax  = fig.add_subplot(111)
ax.plot(df['Time'], df['Detrended'], c='b', label='Detrended')
ax.plot(df['Time'], df['MA'], c='g', label='Moving Average' ,linewidth=7.0)
ax.plot(df['Time'], df['zero'], c='b', label='zero' ,linewidth=2.0)
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: creating the graph is not my intention. my intention is to quantify the up & down swing for each data.